# "aliasing detected during transposition" in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
using Arr = Array<T, Dynamic, 1>;

template <typename T>
using Arr2 = Array<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>;

template <typename T>
Arr2<typename T::Scalar> reshape (const ArrayBase<T> & A, const uint n, const uint m) {
    return Map<const Arr2<typename T::Scalar>>(A.eval().data(), n, m);
}

Arr<double> v = Arr<double>::LinSpaced(16, 0, 15);
auto w = reshape(v, 4, 4).transpose();
std::cout << w << std::endl;
```

which produces the error

> static void Eigen::internal::checkTransposeAliasing_impl::run(const Derived&, const
>   OtherDerived&) [with Derived = Eigen::Array; OtherDerived = Eigen::Transpose >; bool MightHaveTransposeAliasing = true]: Assertion
>   `(!check_transpose_aliasing_run_time_selector ::IsTransposed,OtherDerived>
>   ::run(extract_data(dst), other)) && "aliasing detected during
>   transposition, use transposeInPlace() " "or evaluate the rhs into a
>   temporary using .eval()"' failed.

Adding `eval` indeed fixes the issue:

```
auto w = reshape(v, 4, 4).transpose().eval();
```

(but adding it do the printing line as `<< w.eval() <<` doesn't).

I would like to have a better understanding of what going on and to find out if there's another way to fix this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can only create expression/reference of an existing object. When the object is out of scope, the expression/reference is invalid/undefined.

With `auto w`, you are creating an expression of a temp `Arr2` object, whose life ends after this line , making `w` invalid. The assertion you saw helps check this situation. This temp object is created when you cast a `Map` object to an `Arr2` object at the line of `return`, which involves an undesired data copy from the input vector to the temp `Arr2` object. This happens to be one of [the situations that you should not use `auto`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html). If you would accept one more copy, the following code will work. It is equivalent to you adding `.eval()` in your original code.

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Eigen;

template<typename T>
using Arr = Array<T, Dynamic, 1>;
template<typename T>
using Arr2 = Array<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>;

template<typename T>
Arr2<typename T::Scalar> reshape(const ArrayBase<T> & A, const uint n,
                                 const uint m) {
  return Map<const Arr2<typename T::Scalar>>(A.eval().data(), n, m);
}

int main() {
  Arr<double> v = Arr<double>::LinSpaced(16, 0, 15);
  Arr2<double> w = reshape(v, 4, 4).transpose();
  std::cout << w << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, changing the return type to `Map<const Arr2<typename T::Scalar>>` is a better way to avoid the two copies mentioned above, and you can still use `auto` to keep `w` as an expression. The following code is a better working version.

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Eigen;

template<typename T>
using Arr = Array<T, Dynamic, 1>;
template<typename T>
using Arr2 = Array<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>;

template<typename T>
Map<const Arr2<typename T::Scalar>> reshape(const ArrayBase<T> & A,
                                            const uint n, const uint m) {
  return Map<const Arr2<typename T::Scalar>>(A.eval().data(), n, m);
}

int main() {
  Arr<double> v = Arr<double>::LinSpaced(16, 0, 15);
  auto w = reshape(v, 4, 4).transpose();
  std::cout << w << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

On the other hand, I think your `reshape` is still wrong when A is an expression, as `A.eval().data()` is a temp object whose life ends after the function call. Your `reshape` API will confuse people who don't know this restriction.

Actually creating a reshape function is unnecessary, as constructing a `Map` object itself semantically means reshaping some data in a contiguous memory space. I would recommend the following form. It is only a little bit longer than the word "reshape", no temp buffer/data copy involved, and `auto w` is still an expression object.

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Eigen;

template<typename T>
using Arr = Array<T, Dynamic, 1>;
template<typename T>
using Arr2 = Array<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>;

int main() {
  Arr<double> v = Arr<double>::LinSpaced(16, 0, 15);
  auto w = Map<Arr2<double>>(v.data(), 4, 4).transpose();
  std::cout << w << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would you "reshape" an expression then?

Comment: you `eval()` to a named `Array` object, then `Map`.